# jQuery in Chrome Console (8.0.552.237)

Tags: jquery, console, google-chrome-devtools

It appears that jQuery selectors are not functioning in the Chrome Console.  Any type of selector returns "null".  The scripts do properly run the javascript, however.

Has anyone else noticed this change or know of a fix.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post examples of code that's not working?

Comment: in short, use jQuery in console instead of $

Comment: at 2012-01-23 accessing jquery via $ is now working in Chrome 16.0

Answer (score 17):

I uncovered the cause of this in [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975462/).

The console injects its own function (just a shorthand) for `document.getElementById()`, aliased to `$`, **which shadows jQuery's `$`**. Easy way to check this: when you're at a breakpoint, and jQuery seems to be broken, compare the following in the console:

- `jQuery`
- `$`
- `window.$`

The first and last will be jQuery proper, the local `$` is something like:

```
function () {
    return document.getElementById.apply(document, arguments)
}
```

---

This is because code run from the console is wrapped in a `with` statement:

```
with (window ? window.console._commandLineApi : {}) {
with (window) {
    // the actual code you typed in here
}   
}
```

and `window._commandLineApi.$` is the function that shadows jQuery.

[image: stupid chrome]

---

Found the bug in Chromium for this: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=70969

Comment: or, just type in `jQuery===$`. It will return true if jQuery has control of the $ sign.

Comment: (and, jQuery will return a different looking function, depending on which version of jQuery you're running, so this is easier)

Answer (score 0):

Just run the following command on the console to make it work:

```
$ = jQuery
```