# JQuery .get not working when in external js file?

Tags: jquery, get

I'm trying to clean up the html code on my site, so I moved the jquery code to an external js file. Almost everything works as before only a .get function stopped working.

```
$("#sle").live("click", function() {

    $.get("index.php", function(data){
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });


});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Open your browser's console and see if there are any errors.

Comment: Thats what it returns:dropdown.js:Uncaught TypeError: Object function $(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
} has no method 'get'

Comment: Please see my answer if you already don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Open your browser's console and see if there are any errors. – Matt Ball 8 mins ago

---

> Thats what it returns:dropdown.js:Uncaught TypeError: Object function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); } has no method 'get' – Manuel 3 mins ago

The page is missing jQuery, or another function named `$` is shadowing jQuery.

Try replacing replace `$` with `jQuery`:

```
jQuery("#sle").live("click", function() {
    jQuery.get("index.php", function(data){
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
});
```

However, if the error you commented on only appears when you try to use `$.get()` in the console, then you might be running into [this issue in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796103/jquery-in-chrome-console-8-0-552-237).

Answer (score 4):

This is because the relative position of index.php has changed. it probably is now something like ../somefolder/index.php

Comment: The files are all in the same folder

Answer (score 1):

You're missing jquery library

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The files are all in the same folder

Comment: you're  missing jquery library

Comment: Why jQuery 1.5? That's kind of a random version to suggest.

Comment: Jquery is included on the html page, I only posted the code of the js file

Answer (score 0):

You should probably need to use `jQuery.ready()` function like the one below:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sle").live("click", function() {
        //your code here...
        $.get("index.php", function(data){
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
    }); 

 });
```

or same thing

```
$(function() {})
```

Comment: It's not the source of the problem, and also less of a concern when using `.live()`.