# Why is jQuery's .val() returning null?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit boggled by this...  Why is .val() returning null when there clearly is an option selected for the `<select>`?

These commands were executed via Chrome's console on the page with the issue.

[image]

Comment: @Horen you shouldn't have to do that, which is kinda the point of this question.

Comment: For what it's worth, it works in every version of jquery available to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A2RVE/

Comment: Weird.  I just upgraded to jQuery 1.10.1 - maybe that's causing the problem...

Comment: Seems pedantic but it looks like the selector won't give you a value unless you specify that you want the value of the selected option

Comment: It returns the selected option's value (which just so happens to be available directly on the select, try `$('select[name=template]')[0].value`.)

Comment: Well, I want to know the value of the select element, which is indicated by the options... All I know is that this USED to work in all previous versions of jQuery that I've used... :/

Comment: Maybe jquery just got a bit more strict/pedantic :)

Comment: Note: Just because one of the options has the `selected` attribute doesn't mean that it actually has to be selected. That's the initial selection, and if the user selects another doesn't mean that the attribute changes. However, as there is no way to select no option unless it's a multiple select, one of the options still has to be selected.

Comment: @MrVimes: `select` elements have a `.value` property that will give you the value of the selected element. Even if they didn't it would be easy for jQuery to look at the options and find the selected one.

Comment: I just tested with that specific jQuery version, and it worked.

Comment: I cannot see any reasonable argument for downvoting.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something very obvious... Can those who are voting to close this and voting it down please explain why it's a dumb question? :)

Comment: People are a lot more downvotey than they used to be on Stack sites.  I've had a stackoverflow account for years and only recently do I see lots of questions get downvotes.  Edit:  I accept that people won't be downvoting for the sake of it,  but perhaps a lot less tolerant of small faults with questions than in the past.

Comment: I think they're voting like that because the issue doesn't seem to be reproducible. In this case, the question cannot be answered in its current form.

Comment: My guess is you aren't actually using jQuery, but some other framework that just so happens to also have a .val method because the .val method in 1.10 will *never* return null when an element is selected

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796103/jquery-in-chrome-console-8-0-552-237

Comment: Thanks, @bfavaretto, I'll try to come up with something more reproducible (and probably find the *real* issue in the meantime!)

Comment: What does `$.fn.jquery` give you in the console?

Comment: @rinogo, see Gerve's link in comments. Most likely covers the issue.

Comment: @Yossarian and Gerve - Tried it - Doesn't appear to be my issue.  jQuery() doesn't work either... Hmm.

Comment: @Yossarian I thought that too, but then wouldn't `$.fn.jquery` NOT give `1.10.1`? something strange is going on.

Comment: You're doing the testing in the console at the moment, have you tried testing a simple script in the actual browser?

Comment: @Yossarian: That's referring to a really old version of Chrome. There would be a TypeError in the console when calling `.val()` if that was the case here.

Comment: I think @Guffa is right, though it does seem possible to set the select element to no selection in Chrome by assigning `null` to the `.value` of the select. Doesn't work in FF though. http://jsfiddle.net/pzGnV/

Comment: ...to verify, try `$("select[name=template] option:selected").length`

Comment: Agreed, it is definitely possible to reproduce the console screenshot in the question if `val` is being set to `null` somewhere first [as here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OUvnU.png)

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be a bug in Chrome.  Maybe a bug between my specific version of Chrome and this specific version of jQuery?  The `select` in question (which was previously hidden, but unhidden for further testing) appears like so:

[image]

This suggests that an option is not selected.

However, clicking on it (to *open* the select element and display the options, not actually clicking on an option) reveals this:

[image]

Weird.  Very weird.  Soooo if the GUI is reflecting the state of things, part of Chrome thinks that the select element has an option selected, while another part of the code thinks the select element does not have an option selected?  Weird.

Comment: By the way, the select element is added in this case via an indirect method - the culprit of the problem is likely the plugin/code adding the element...